# reserve() Implementation for std::vector in STL

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Consider this implementation of std::vector::reserve() from the book "The C++ Programming Language, 4th ed., Bjarne Stroustrup:

```
template<class T, class A>
void vector<T,A>::reserve(size_type newalloc)
{
    if (newalloc<=capacity()) return;
    vector_base<T,A> b {vb.alloc,newalloc};          // get new storage
                                                     // (see PS of question for details on vb data member)

    T* src  = elem;                                  // ptr to the start of old storage
    T* dest = b.elem;                                // ptr to the start of new storage       
    T* end  = elem+size();                           // past-the-end ptr to old storage
    for (; src!=end; ++src, ++dest) {
        new(static_cast<void*>(dest)) T{move(*src)}; // move construct
        src–>~T();                                   // destroy
    }

    swap(vb,b);                                      // install new base (see PS if needed)
} // implicitly release old space(when b goes out of scope)
```

Note that in the loop, for each element in vector, at least one call is made to a ctor and a dtor(possibly triggering more such calls if the element's class has bases, or if the class or its bases have data members with ctors). (In the book, for-loop is actually a separate function, but I injected it into the reserve() here for simplicity.)

Now consider my suggested alternative:

```
template<class T, class A>
void vector<T,A>::reserve(size_type newalloc)
{
    if (newalloc<=capacity()) return;
    vector_base<T,A> b {vb.alloc,newalloc};    // get new space

    memcpy(b.elem, elem, sz);                  // copy raw memory
                                               // (no calls to ctors or dtors)

    swap(vb,b);                                // install new base
} // implicitly release old space(when b goes out of scope)
```

To me, it seems like the end result is the same, minus the calls to ctors/dtors.

Is there a situation where this alternative would fail, and if so, where is the flaw?

---

P.S. I don't think it is much relevant, but here are the data members of `vector` and `vector_base` classes:

```
// used as a data member in std::vector
template<class T, class A = allocator<T> >
struct vector_base {                    // memory structure for vector
     A alloc;       // allocator
     T* elem;       // start of allocation
     T* space;      // end of element sequence, start of space allocated for possible expansion
     T* last;       // end of allocated space

     vector_base(const A& a, typename A::size_type n)
         : alloc{a}, elem{alloc.allocate(n)}, space{elem+n}, last{elem+n} { }
     ~vector_base() { alloc.deallocate(elem,last–elem); } // releases storage only, no calls 
                                                          // to dtors: vector's responsibility        
     //...
};

// std::vector
template<class T, class A = allocator<T> >
class vector {
     vector_base<T,A> vb;            // the data is here
     void destroy_elements();
public:
     //...
};
```

Comment: This would fail if the elements keep a pointer to themselves, or rely on their own address. It would be enough if they e.g. made a copy of the this pointer, or copied the this pointer into a lambda or something like that.

Comment: @AaronI This proposal is UB, plain and simple, hence why Bjarne and co, who know better, didn't use it. Having said that... any element that can use a pointer to itself is an object, so it doesn't need to store its own address, because it can always access it using `this` within a method. And because the `this` pointer doesn't notionally exist - it's generated at call-time for whichever object on which a method is invoked - it can't become wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might fail:

- `memcpy()` will work only if you have a vector of POD.
- It will fail for all other kind of objects as it doesn't respect the semantic of the objects it copies (copy construction).

Example of issues:

- If the constructor of the object sets some internal pointers to internal members, your `memcpy()` will copy the value of the original pointer, which will not be updated correctly and continue to point to a memory region that will be released.
- If the object contains a `shared_ptr`, the object count will become inconsistent (`memcpy()` will duplicate the pointer without incrementing its reference count, then `swap()` will make sure that the original shared pointer will be in b, which will be released, so that the shared pointer reference count will be decremented).

As pointed out by T.C in the comments, as soon as your vector stores non-POD data the `memcpy()` results in UB (undefined behaviour).

Comment: It's just UB, period, for non-trivially-copyable types. There's no living object at the destination.

Comment: @T.C. Of course it's UB ! I thought however that it was worth trying to explain to `memcpy` addicts  and with `memcpy` arguments that an object is more than the sum of its memories ;-)

Comment: Sure, but it's worth emphasizing that it's UB in the general case and the implementation is free to make your cat pregnant, even if the class at issue is `struct A { ~A() {} };`.

Comment: @T.C. What does "UB" stand for, again?

Comment: @Christophe Even the 1st point in "Example of Issues" alone is enough for me, but I couldn't make sense of the 2nd point. No object(including `shared_ptr`) gets released in b, or anything else for that matter. `vector_base` dtor only releases storage memory. It doesn't call dtors for the elements in storage. What am I missing?

Comment: UB == Undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Kemal intially, vb is a vector of T containing your objects before reservation.  b is a local vector of T that you create with sufficient size.  You then do memcpy of objects in vb to b.  Then you swap to install b into vb.  But in the same time, what was in vb is then in b (so your iniial vector elements).  When you return from the function the local variable b gets destroyed. This is where the bad things of 2nd bullet would happen.

Comment: @Christophe, I understand that local b gets destroyed. But dtor of b does not release anything, say a `shared_ptr` as a data member of an element. On a side note, neither vb, nor b are vectors.

Comment: @Kemal ok ! I didn't look at the details of vector_base implementation.  I thought is t was some kind of simplified vectors.  You can indeed in this case forget about the second bullet.

Comment: POD is too strong, btw. You only need trivially copyable.

Comment: @T.C. Indeed. The standard defines trivially copyable on the base of a memcpy to and from a char array. Standard layout may not be required.